# repesent digits using regular expression

Tags: grep

```
grep -w "ing_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"
```

The command mentioned above is working. But is there a short version of 4 digits?

This does not work:

```
grep -w "ing_[0-9]\+ {4}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grep by default use Basic Regular expressions. In BRE , you need to escape the curly braces so that it would consider the curly braces as repetition quantifier.

```
grep -w "ing_[0-9]\{4\}" file
```

**Example:**

```
$ echo 'ing_6786 says' | grep -w "ing_[0-9]{4}"
$ echo 'ing_6786 says' | grep -w "ing_[0-9]\{4\}"
ing_6786 says
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are lucky and your `grep` supports modern (*Perl*) regular expressions, try `-P` argument

```
grep -wP "ing_[0-9]{4}"
```